# Данные в цикле

Tags: php

Уважаемые гуру. Изучаю недолгое время php. Прошу помочь разобраться.
Есть вывод данных в цикле такого типа :

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
{
$pdf->Row(array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5]));
}

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо выводимых значений $row[0] я мог подставить свои значения в зависимости от id записи в базе. Т.е. сделать в данных условиях что-то типа

if($row["id"] == '1' or $row["id"] == '2' or $row["id"] == '3' or $row["id"] == '4') {
$row[0] = $S_1;
}

Если выражаюсь невнятно, прошу вас не сильно критиковать - я новечек ...

Заранее спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

ну вы по-моему все уже сами написали

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
   if ($row['id'] >= 1 && $row['id'] <= 4) {
       $row[0] = $S_1;
   }
   $pdf->Row(array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5]));
}
```